# Replacement for transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication, upgrade

My colleagues and I have to migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012.

Schema, triggers, stored procedures etc. are working fine. But we also have to "migrate" the replication mechanism.

Replication is used to transfer data from the intranet to the dmz and vice versa. (There can be edits on both sides!!)

At the moment we use transactional replication with updatable subscribers.
The problem is: this mechanism isn't available in SQL Server 2012 any more.

Question: what is my best option to replace that feature?

Requirements:

- Internal and external database can be edited
- Near "real time". Maximum time until the edits show up in the other database sould be around 10 minutes.
- Due to restrictions from the clients security team the connection attempts between databases may only be initiated from the internal database.

If I am correct Microsoft advises to use peer to peer replication as a replacement, but I am not sure that we can use that because of the security restriction.

Read/Write speed is not our first concern because there are only ~3000 users.
The application uses Entity Framework 4.5 (if that matters).

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you read up on merge replication?  I think that should allow you to do what you're asking (bidirectional).  I haven't used it firsthand so I wouldn't be the SME but it sounds like that's the droid you're looking for.

Comment: Transactional replication with updatable subscribers is still available in SQL Server 2012. Only thing is you will have to implement it using T-SQL as GUI option has been removed.